# Check if mocked function called with all elements of array

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have a list of expected arguments, I need to check if the given function is called with all elements of the list. I came up with this. I know looping is better way.

```
expected_list = [(1,2,3),(4,5,6)]
real_writer = mock.Mock()
real_writer.write.assert_any_call(expected_list[0])
real_writer.write.assert_any_call(expected_list[1])
```

Is there any way where I can pass the list itself??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking whether function has been called multiple times with different parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34225688/checking-whether-function-has-been-called-multiple-times-with-different-paramete)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
expected_list = [(1,2,3),(4,5,6)]
real_writer = mock.Mock()
real_writer.write.assert_has_calls((mock.call(exp) for exp in expected_list), any_order=True)
```

If you actually expect the calls to be in the order they are in the list you can omit the `any_order` argument.

Comment: In the OP context is clear that he `any_order=False` to mimic his code. You should point out that `assert_has_calls` match even in the case that there are more calls.

Comment: @Micheled'Amico  How is it clear that `any_order=False` is what he needs? It doesn't matter what order they call `assert_any` in. Also, I can make a note about the semantics of `assert_any` but I assume the OP understood this already. My code mimics what theirs does in this respect as well.